# Given list of countries draw map with those countries a different color

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, matplotlib, processing

Looking to the do what the title says - produce a world map image that colors particular countries.  I'm open to platform - Processing or Python/Basemap preferable.  Web based service ok if it has an API.

Anyone have direction on this?

Comment: Is this a one-off? Or for a web page? For a dynamic web page that might be different for different users? For an application?

Comment: First step is 20 images - each built from a list of 10 countries.  Second step would be those 20 images over time, so many hundreds of images.  Presentation for first step is image, second step is web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Geomap](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geomap.html) did the trick here.

It's part of their chart visualizations tools.  A javascript call that returns an SVG map colored according to data that you provide.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at [GIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_information_system)? There are a number of open source and free clients that allow you to work with various maps (probably .dwg) with various corresponding data in xml format to produce geographical visualizations through queries and you can export a number of formats. I think this would give you either the visualization that you want or the data to plug into processing or whatever to create it.

Answer (score 0):

Get the map data in shapefile format, look at python bindings to OGR and GDAL, or maybe try Fiona: http://sgillies.net/blog/1095/fiona/ or SciPy, or just download Qgis www.qgis.org and learn some GIS skills.

Country-level shapefiles for the world are fairly widely available www.gadm.org maybe.